# "ELF file OS ABI invalid" using psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

I've post [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024140/flask-psycopg2-object-has-no-attribute-cursor-while-inserting), but I think the problem is maybe specific. So I create this new post.

When I test in the python's console psycopg2, I've this error :

```
this-user@xxx-web:~/my-folder$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import sys,os
>>> import psycopg2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/users/this-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: /home/users/this-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: ELF file OS ABI invalid
>>> quit()

this-user@xxx-web:~/massifs$ ll /home/users/this-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so

-rwxr-xr-x 1 this-user 214K mai   21  2015 /home/users/this-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so*
```

If I run the python's console in root, it's working !!?? :(

Thanks for help.
F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your import is from a 'user' install, so if you run it as root, it will import something else (a different copy of the module which happens to work). You may have two installs of the `psycopg2` module and the one that is in `this-user` is not compatible (maybe you copied it directly from another host rather than installing it with `pip`).

You should probably un-install `psycopg2` and re-install it properly with `python -m pip uninstall --user psycopg2` and then `python -m pip install --user psycopg2`, so you get the correct build of the `.so` file.

Comment: So, I try to install with "--no-deps", but psycopg2 is already installed in "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages". I think is ok, no ?. But I've again an error with psycopg2 : " object has no attribute 'cursor' "

Comment: I remove all the psycopg2 libs, and (re)install it. It's ok now. Thanks